# integration testing in Grails: what is the correct way?

Tags: grails, integration-testing

I'm entirely new to Grails and it's testing functions since I started my current job approx 4 months ago.   The person who trained me on testing left our group several weeks ago, and now I'm on my own for testing.   What I've slowing been discovering is that the way I was trained on how to do Grails integration testing is almost entirely different from the way(s) that I've seen people do it on the forums and support groups.  I could really use some guidance on which way is right/best.   I'm currently working in Grails 2.4.0, btw.

Here is a sample mockup of an integration test in the style that I was trained on.  Is this the right or even the best way that I should be doing it?

```
@Test
void "test a method in a controller"() { 

def fc = new FooController() // 1. Create controller

fc.springSecurityService = [principal: [username: 'somebody']]  // 2. Setup Inputs
fc.params.id = '1122' 

fc.create()  // 3. Call the method being tested

assertEquals "User Not Found", fc.flash.errorMessage   // 4. Make assertions on what was supposed to happen
assertEquals "/", fc.response.redirectUrl

}
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Since Grails 2.4.0 is used, you can leverage the benefit of using [spock framework](http://spockframework.github.io/spock/docs/1.0/index.html) by default.

<kbd>**[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17871827/2051952)**</kbd> is sample unit test case which you can model after to write Integration specs.

**Note:**

- Integration specs goes to `test/integration`
- should inherit [**`IntegrationSpec`**](http://grails.github.io/grails-doc/2.3.x/api/grails/test/spock/IntegrationSpec.html).
- Mocking is not needed. `@TestFor` is not used as compared to unit spec.
- DI can be used to full extent. `def myService` at class level will inject the service in 
  spec.
- Mocking not required for domain entities.

Above spec should look like:

```
import grails.test.spock.IntegrationSpec

class FooControllerSpec extends IntegrationSpec {

    void "test a method in a controller"() { 
        given: 'Foo Controller'
        def fc = new FooController()

        and: 'with authorized user'
        fc.springSecurityService = [principal: [username: 'somebody']]

        and: 'with request parameter set'
        fc.params.id = '1122' 

        when: 'create is called'
        fc.create()

        then: 'check redirect url and error message'
        fc.flash.errorMessage == "User Not Found"
        fc.response.redirectUrl == "/"
    }
}
```

Comment: There are typos in your code sample. You have declared a variable named `fc` and later refer to `fcc` in a couple different places.

Comment: Thanks @JeffScottBrown. Copied from the question. Did not see that while tailoring up the spec. Updated question as well.

Comment: thanks all,  is there any benefit in using Spock vs. JUnit for testing?  efficiency?  Easy of use?

Comment: You get BDD with spock. It is intuitive and easy to use. For example, data driven testing. Go through the docs as shown in the answer, you will find it useful.

Comment: I was observing that many examples on http://docs.grails.org/latest/guide/testing.html#unitTestingURLMappings extend "Specification" instead of "IntegrationSpec" for example...not sure what the difference I am having trouble testing the controllers (in their examples they do not call new FooController either)

Comment: @ColinD Above answer is applicable for Grails 2.*. Grails 3 uses `@Integration` class level annotation and extends `Specification` instead.

Comment: @dmahapatro thanks for the details. It appeared that the grails 2.x documentation was actually a little confusing in this case, since the current documentation uses grails 3.x format. I opened this github issue to try to clarify https://github.com/grails/grails-doc/issues/476

Comment: Fun fact: if you use `@TestFor` by accident, Grails (2.5.6) will not make the test fail then and there, but instead break the bootstrapped application context somehow (a static member set in `BootStrap.groovy` was `null`) for all tests that run _after_ that class. Joy.